# Use some PartialView with post action in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

There is a view for registration that has two PartialView in jquery tab (register by phone or register by email).

[image]

I was Called those in Parent view with below codes:

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#section-1" class="fa fa-mobile"><span>موبایل</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-2" class="fa fa-envelope"><span>ایمیل</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        <section id="section-1">
            @Html.Partial("_MobileRegister", new S6.ViewModels.MobileRegister())
        </section>
        <section id="section-2">
            @Html.Partial("_EmailRegister" , new S6.ViewModels.EmailRegister())
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller and actions:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

public PartialViewResult _MobileRegister()
{
    return PartialView("_MobileRegister");
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MobileRegister(MobileRegister model)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
     }
     return PartialView("~/Views/Account/_MobileRegister.cshtml", model);
}
```

Now, when data post to action, if the `ModelState` is not valid or for any reason that causes the `return PartialView` to be called, PartialView is shown in seprated page.

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a complete example here:

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp-net-mvc-using-ajax-helpers-with-razor-partial-views

Answer (score 2):

If you don't return anything in the

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
     }
```

your funtion will always return the PartialView. Add a return statement in that if.

Comment: that is an example and not complete. Yes, in that block i have return to another action. but if ModelState is not valid?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to render "Partial Views" on the other view, you have to use Ajax instead direct post. `Ajax.BeginForm` is a good solution.